# setting selected value via querySelector function

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors, selectors-api

I use `<template>` element to render a table's row. A `<select>` element inside in a row and I try to set selected value but the code didn't work for me.

```
<template id="template">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control status">
                <option value="1">In Progress</option>
                <option value="2">Done</option>
                <option value="3">Canceled</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Than I call this function below.

```
$.each(data.Object, function (index, item) {

            var template = document.querySelector('#template');

            template.content.querySelector('.select > option[value="' + item.Status + '"]').selected = true;


            var cloneAction = document.importNode(template.content, true);
            var tbody = document.querySelector("#mytbody");
            tbody.appendChild(cloneAction);


        })
```

Comment: Use `$('#template select > option[value="' + item.Status + '"]').prop('selected', true);`

Comment: didnt work .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- First of all, your selector needs to be `select ...` and not `.select ...`
- An easier way to set the selected option is to set the `value` on the `<select>` element itself.
- And finally:

It looks like some state info is lost on `document.importNode()`, so you need to wait until you have the cloned element to set that state:

```
var template = document.querySelector('#template');

//Works:
template.content.querySelector('label').textContent = item.Name;
template.content.querySelector('input').checked = true;
//Doesn't work until the elements is cloned:
//template.content.querySelector('select').value = item.Status;

var cloneAction = document.importNode(template.content, true);

//Now it works:
cloneAction.querySelector('select').value = item.Status;
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8pervtto/